# Love the design

Tags: discussion

Not a question, just an appreciation: I absolutely **love** the graphic design of the unix.stackexchange.com site. Love it. Spot-on for what the site's about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually the standard SE beta design; we don't have a site-specific design yet. See [Why does this site look so "sketchy"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#sketchy) in the FAQ

Comment: Ah. Well, FWIW, it's a great design for USE, too. :-) I tend to associate \*nix with engineering and science, you see (because I'm that old), and this graph paper, pencil motif just works perfectly.